# Paraview 5.0.1 on Xenial: "find data" leads to segmentation fault

Tags: 16.04, segmentation-fault

I am using Paraview 5.0.1 from the Xenial repositories. Trying to select data using the "find data" menu leads to a segmentation fault. 
The same version of Paraview is installed by OpenFoam 4.1 and works without problems. The only difference I could see is that "MPI Enabled" is "On" in the Xenial version and "Off" in the OpenFoam version.
Any hints how to fix this problem in the Xenial version?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the MPI has anything to do with that. Try downloading the latest "binary" file from [Paraview website](http://www.paraview.org/download/) ans simply unzip and use it.

Here is the link to the [Paraview tutorial](http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/images/f/f7/ParaViewTutorial51.pdf), see Exercise 2.27 page 59. You can download the `can.ex2` file from [here](https://midas3.kitware.com/midas/item/207317). It should work easily.

Here is a screenshot used with 5.2 (same with 5.3)
[image]